# how to replace email address from html innertext

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i have a problem, for replacing email address from html innertext.

i can replace all email address. but i can't replace only specific(innertext of html). please help me..

i have tried with `preg_replace('/[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}|[A-Z0-9.-]+)/iu','[---]',$data)`

please help me. thanks...

**my input**

```
<div  data="example1@dom.com,example4@dom.com"><a href="example1@dom.com" > example4@dom.com,  <b>example3@dom.com</b>  other text, example7@dom.com, ,<i>example5@dom.com</i></a></div >
```

**expected output:**

```
<div  data="example1@dom.com,example4@dom.com"><a href="example1@dom.com" > [--],  <b>[--]</b>  other text, [--] ,<i>[--]</i></a></div >
```

[live demo](http://regex101.com/r/kH2bY7/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through PCRE verb `(*SKIP)(*F)`.

```
<[^<>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}|[A-Z0-9.-]+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/7)

`<[^<>]*>` matches all the tags and the following PCRE verb `(*SKIP)(*F)` makes the match to fail completely. Then the regex engine tries to match the pattern which was at the right of `|` symbol against the remaining string.

```
$re = "/<[^<>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}|[A-Z0-9.-]+)/mi";
$str = "<div data=\"example1@dom.com,example4@dom.com\"><a href=\"example1@dom.com\" > example4@dom.com, <b>example3@dom.com</b> other text, example7@dom.com, ,<i>example5@dom.com</i></a></div >\n";
$subst = "[---]";
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo $result;
```

**Output:**

```
<div data="example1@dom.com,example4@dom.com"><a href="example1@dom.com" > [---], <b>[---]</b> other text, [---], ,<i>[---]</i></a></div >
```

Comment: many many thanks, and can i replace with another pattern (`[0-9]{6,}`) matching like as phone number , special word after skype: any_word etc

Comment: yes, you can replace the email id pattern with another pattern.

Comment: can i get this output `M:[---]sdsd M:[---]sdfsd M:[---]` for input `M: <any_tag>+48 668 157 750</any_tag>
sdsd
<b>M:</b> +48(22) 722 65 50  [demo](http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/12)
sdfsd
M: +48(22)<any_tag>247</any_tag> 81 34`  by using like pattern `<[^<>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|(m:)[0-9\+\s\(\)\,]{3,}` ..  please help me for this advance regex.

Comment: could you explain what are you trying to do?

Comment: [see demo](http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/12). then you can understand. i mean have to hide some mobile, fax no by key word like `m:` , `fax:`. but this input is mixed html text like previous comment..

Comment: could you format your expected output? I think it's better to ask it as a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66017/discussion-between-ahosan-karim-asik-and-avinash-raj).

Answer (score 1):

```
[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}(?![^<]*>)|[A-Z0-9.-]+)(?![^<]*>)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/6

```
$re = "/[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}(?![^<]*>)|[A-Z0-9.-]+)(?![^<]*>)/mi";
$str = "<div data=\"example1@dom.com,example4@dom.com\"><a href=\"example1@dom.com\" > example4@dom.com, <b>example3@dom.com</b> other text, example7@dom.com, ,<i>example5@dom.com</i></a></div >";
$subst = "[---]";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Output:`<div data="example1@dom.com,example4@dom.com"><a href="example1@dom.com" > [---], <b>[---]</b> other text, [---], ,<i>[---]</i></a></div >`

Comment: thanks, and can i replace with another pattern matching like as `phone number , special word after skype: any_word` etc

Comment: @AhosanKarimAsik yes `$subst` .you can give this any value you wanna replace with

Comment: no, i said that another pattern `[0-9]{6,}` like email pattern.