# how to get all the html tags in hierarchy except its content?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I want to get the html tags pattern or layout of given html content.

e.g: The following is the given html content

```
<p style="font-size: 11px">
  <strong>Sample Director</strong><br>
  ABC Name<br>
  Test Sign Association<br>
  12345 N. 85th Ave., Ste. D345<br>
  Test, NY  85308<br>
  Wk.:  602-385-1234;  Cell:   602-079-1234<br>
  Fax:  602-987-1244<br>
  <a href="mailto:abce@test.org">abce@test.org</a> 
</p>
```

Desired output:

```
<p><strong></strong><br><br><br><br><a></a></p>
```

I've checked with some of the regex and gem but they all provide solutions for removing tags. I've tried with `tr` but that's resulting only in `</>`

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Comment: @Biffen Ok, thanks for the useful info of not using regex on a language. I've however used Nokogiri too, to parse the html but it doesn't have a method to get all the child node tags. Any help there?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
(<\/?\w+)(*SKIP)(*F)|[\w\s\.\:\-"'\=\@\,\;]+       // replace with ""(blank)
```

or

```
  (<\/?\w+)(*SKIP)(*F)|[^<>]+
```

**[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/bB4pA0/1)**  or [update demo](https://regex101.com/r/bB4pA0/2)

Comment: Great... Can you plz explain REGEX

Comment: @Hetal Khunti `(<\/?\w+)(*SKIP)(*F)` this part for skip tag word with `<tag`  and next part match any char without `<>`

Comment: @Avinash Raj i have tried with php. i don't know ruby. if it helps him then better.

Comment: ruby won't support the above PCRE verb.

Comment: ok, please help him. and this regex was your.  you give me answer in one ques.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27243724/4073753)

Comment: @AhosanKarimAsik thanks for a quick help. But, the expression won't work for ruby, like Avinash Raj said.